# ESP32 and Raspberry Pi connection issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, esp32

I have a problem with the serial connection between an ESP32 and a Raspberry Pi.

I have two simple example codes as follows, one made in python to read the data in RPi and the other to send a message by serial constantly.

```
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=0.1)
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()[:-2] #the last bit gets rid of the new-line chars
    if data:
        print data
```

Once connected the following happens:

1. I activate the python script and the data is read correctly.
2. If I turn off the script using CTRL+C
3. I activate the python script again
4. No data is displayed
5. The same happens if I connect and disconnect the USB cable.
6. If I restart the ESP32 then it starts working again (but I can't restart it constantly).

I also try with cat command but it only work one time, after trying CTRL+C and doing it again it does not print anything in the command terminal

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I did this same test with the arduino serial terminal in windows but it works perfectly, connecting or disconnecting, it always resumes the data acquisition.

Should I take something else into account that I am not seeing at the hardware level?

It should be noted that the ports are active and I can receive data, the problem is when the operation is restarted when the script does not seem to accept it anymore. Is the port then unused?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a keyboard interrupt to properly close the serial port when you quit the script.

```
import serial

with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=0.1) as ser:
    run = True
    while run:
        try:
            data = ser.readline()[:-2] #the last BYTES gets rid of the new-line chars
            if data:
                print data
        except KeyboardInterrupt: // Responds to ctrl-c
           run = False

    ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting data from Esp32 to Raspberry pi, you first need to install Arduino IDE on Raspberry pi from (https://www.arduino.cc/en/software). Make sure you have install Linux ARM 32/64 bit version on raspberry pi. Then install it. After installing it you need to open it on background while Serial monitor should be on. Hopefully you can get your data from Esp without any interruption.